# Add WYSIWYG Editor to Block Form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, blocks, adminform, wysiwyg

How do you add a WYSIWYG editor to a custom form which you create through a block? I [have found this article for doing this through UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804007/magento-2-ui-component-wysiwyg/42804008) components but need this for a block.

I've tried the following:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'content',
            'editor',
            [
                'name' => 'content',
                'label' => __('Body'),
                'title' => __('Body'),
                'rows' => '5',
                'cols' => '30',
                'wysiwyg' => true,
                'required' => true
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Discovered I was missing the Config setting:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
 */
protected $_wysiwygConfig;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
 * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

**Meaning I could do the following:**

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'content',
    'editor',
    [
        'name' => 'content',
        'label' => __('Body'),
        'title' => __('Body'),
        'rows' => '5',
        'cols' => '30',
        'wysiwyg' => true,
        'config' => $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(),
        'required' => true
    ]
);
```

Type must be set to *editor* and wysiwyg set to *true* for this to work.

Comment: magezon page builder is not working for this editor.

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined on Magento 2.4 are you getting the same error ?

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple dont do all this  things just put below code in 
app\code\NameSpace\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\module_module_form.xml

```
<field name="content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">content</item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-wide</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Comment: see below ansvwer

Comment: works but shows in full length

Answer (score 3):

@Avesh Naik you can use below code to add the wysiwyg field in UI Form, it will add field with the form width, you will not face the fullwidth issue with field.

```
    <field name="front_message2" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">lrpricerules</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">150px</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Front end message2</label>
            <dataScope>front_message2</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <rows>5</rows>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

upvote for me if its useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="description_custom" template="ui/form/field" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Description Custom</label>
                <dataScope>description_custom</dataScope>
                <notice translate="true">Note: Keyboard shortcut to activate editor help : Alt + 0 (Windows) or &#x2325;0 (MacOS)</notice>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                    <settings>
                        <rows>8</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```