# Page Builder not working for the custom ui form admin

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.4.2, page-builder

I have added the page builder in my admin form.But when I try to click on the setting icon for the elements it does not work.

```
 <field name="description" formElement="wysiwyg" sortOrder="90">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">storelocator</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
            <label translate="true">Store View</label>
            <dataScope>description</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year late, but for anyone who has the same problem:

Add this to the layout xml that's loading the ui component

```
<update handle="styles"/>
<update handle="editor"/>
```

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, add wysiwyg config data in component

```
<field name="description" formElement="wysiwyg" sortOrder="90">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">storelocator</item>
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">150px</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
        </validation>
        <label translate="true">Store View</label>
        <dataScope>description</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg>
            <settings>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried the above code but not working.

Comment: Check code here is working for you or not https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/306876/84221

Comment: Not working tried the link

Comment: Not working for me as well. Any idea?